# Align table and wrap text arround it

Tags: tables, text-manipulation

I'm trying to do something I'm not sure I can. So, let me explain. I have an `enumerate` environment. Inside of it, there are 5 images within an array and then a table.

To the right of that table I want to write text until the table's end is reached, and continue at the next line, but what I get is that:
[image]

---

EDIT 1

Werner asked if I can post my attempt to use wraptable, so here it is:

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{5.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente de Curtosis}} \\ \hline
 & \textbf{sexo=0} & \textbf{sexo=1} \\ \hline
\textbf{Peso} & 4,37531 & 1,21824 \\ \hline
\textbf{Altura} & -0,97849 & 0,946925 \\ \hline
\textbf{Zapato} & -0,28973 & -0,620593 \\ \hline
\textbf{Dinero} & 6,88646 & 2,99526 \\ \hline
\textbf{Tiempo} & -0,497143 & 0,106985 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

---

EDIT 2: all the files for te example asked by Bernard - [LaTeX files](https://mega.nz/#!GhAEXBoI!pR_tYcX8ot4S_3iDEXNHISkEPIx-GNy8hDdWBPm3H5M)

---

And I want that but when the right side is full of text.  I tried with \begin{wraptable} but It doesn't work. Could you help me?

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Can you show us your attempt with [`wraptable`](http://ctan.org/pkgwraptable)?

Comment: @Werner: In the neighbourhood of (or within) an enumerate environment, there will be problems.

Comment: ,@adolphenom Does [Including wraptable in itemize list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/including-wraptable-in-itemize-list) help?

Comment: @Werner I editted the first post to put into it :)

Comment: @Bernard It's possible, but I don't know :(

Comment: @AboAmmar I'm not sure about it, but I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: There is no problem with the code you posted.  As I said in a previous command, you may have problems using `wraptable` in the neighbourhood ofa a list environment, and precisely, you mentioned `enumerate`. Could you post a minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard I uploaded the small example and it's in the post. I hope it's enough :)

Comment: @adolphenom: I've posted a solution, without `wrapfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, based on the  plain tex set of macros `insbox`. I defined `\InsertListR` command, based on the original `\InsertBoxR` command. It takes $2$ arguments: the number of lines untouched before insertion of a box, and the inserted contents. An optional argument can be used in case the number of required shorter lines is not well calculated: the number of supplementary shorter lines. You cannot have a caption with this code.

I took the opportunity to simplify the rest of the code  and improve your table, loading the `siunitx` package for the vertical alignment of the numbers in the cells, and `cellspace`, to have some vertical padding of the rows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{S}
% # START ## Márgenes #
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    height=24cm, % height of the text block
    width=17cm, % width of the text block
    top=3cm, % distance of the text block from the top of the page
    headheight=1.7cm, % height for the header block
    headsep=1.5cm, % distance from the header block to the text block1
    footskip=1cm,
}
% # END ## Márgenes #
% # START # Paquete para añadir imágenes
% Centrar imagen
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo-uc3m2}
%\centering
%\end{figure}
% # END # Paquete para añadir imágenes
% # START ## Fuente #
\usepackage{mathpazo,euler}
\linespread{1.00}
% # END ## Fuente #
% # START ## Quitar sangría inicial #
% Poner \indent para indentar.
% Poner \noindent para quitar indentación.
\newlength\tindent
\setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{\tindent}}
% # END ## Quitar sangría inicial #

        \input{insbox}
        \makeatletter
        \@InsertBoxMargin = 12pt
        \makeatother
        \geometry{showframe, nomarginpar}
        \usepackage{etoolbox}

        \newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\pretocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
        %
        \newcommand{\InsertListL}[3][]{%
        \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
        \InsertBoxL{#2}{#3}[#1]\par \hspace{\itemindent}
        }%
        \newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]{%
        \par\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
        \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]
        }%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Algunas de las variables de este fichero presenta bimodalidad debido a diferencias entre chicos y chicas. Utilizando los histogramas y el coeficiente de curtosis, indica en qué variable es más acusada esta bimodalidad (compara sólo las variables peso, altura, zapato, dinero (que llevan en el bolsillo) y tiempo (que tardan en llegar a la universidad)). Justifica la respuesta.
        \begin{figure}[hp]
          \centering
          \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \includegraphics[width=2.85in]{DATA/histogram_peso-sexo_3-4}
            \includegraphics[width=2.85in]{DATA/histogram_altura-sexo_3-4} & \\[2ex]
            \includegraphics[width=2.85in]{DATA/histogram_zapato-sexo_3-4.png}
            \includegraphics[width=2.85in]{DATA/histogram_dinero-sexo_3-4} & \\[2ex]
            \includegraphics[width=2.85in]{DATA/histogram_tiempo-sexo_3-4}
          \end{tabular}
        \end{figure}%

        \InsertListR[4]{0}{
          \begin{tabular}{|Cl|*{2}{S[table-format =-1.6]|}}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|Cc|}{\textbf{Coeficiente de Curtosis}} \\ \hline
                            & {\textbf{sexo=0}} & {\textbf{sexo=1}} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Peso} & 4,37531 & 1,21824 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Altura} & -0,97849 & 0,946925 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Zapato} & -0,28973 & -0,620593 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Dinero} & 6,88646 & 2,99526 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Tiempo} & -0,497143 & 0,106985 \\ \hline
          \end{tabular}}

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's just what I wanted, thank you so much!

One more thing... How can I take off the big box you put in the paper? :-)

Comment: Oh that's the option `showframe` option of the geometry package. I added it just to check everything was placed at the right place. So remove the `\geometry{showframe, nomarginpar}` line.

Comment: Thank you, @Bernar. One more question, I swear. I added your changes to my final documment, but the item has been displaced to the right as I did a tabulation, but I didn't. I don't know if you know what I mean...

Comment: I don't see very well. Which item do you mean? the `\item` of the enumerate environment. Could you post a link to (part of) your document,, so I can see what's happening?

Comment: it's supposed to look like http://i.imgur.com/Jkr7mwo.png, but it's actually look so: http://i.imgur.com/tEBXlMY.png

Comment: I added another `\item` after the wrapped table, but I can't reproduce the problem. Could you post or make a link to a minimal (non)working example?

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55fdcd8bdee2074478001a8a

Look at the second item. Forget about the table and that stuff. Do you see it's displaced to the right instead of being like 1? :)

Comment: The problem came the figure environment above. I added a `\par` before the initial `mbox{}` in the definition of `\InsertBoxR` (see my updated code). Alternatively, you might insert a blank line after the end of the figure environment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, @Bernard! You save hours of work! =D