# How to set default value of optional argument exactly in function?

Tags: macros, wrap

I have two problems.

1. I have an mechanism. It gives me correct number of lines, which I should make narrow (I have it in `\setcounter{ct}{...}`). And I want to teach `\addpicture` that skill and use it as **default** for the first optional argument. How can I do it?

In nutshell I want default value of optional argument of `\addpicture` to be calculated every time running this macro based on mandatory arguments of function `\addpicture`.

But I see that I will not success in this case because the third agrument of `\addpicture` is not a number of narrow lines. So,

2. The third argument of `\InsertBoxL` is number of additional lines which should be narrower too. In documentation it is said **correction**. But in my function it spoils due to some mystical things. So, what it is now, and what shall I do to correct it?

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}              
   \usepackage{forloop}
   \usepackage{caption}
   \usepackage{xargs}
   \usepackage{mwe}    
   \input{insbox.tex}
   \usepackage{threeparttable}
   \newcounter{ct}

   \newlength\imageheight

   \newcount\narrowlinect
   \narrowlinect=0\relax

   \newcommandx\addpicture[4][1=5,3=0]{%
   \InsertBoxL{#3}{\begin{threeparttable}%
   \begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}%
   \captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]}

   \begin{document}
   \settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
   \narrowlinect=\imageheight\relax
   \setcounter{ct}{\numexpr((\narrowlinect)/\baselineskip+2)\relax}

   \arabic{ct}

   \addpicture[0]{example-image-a}[0]{0.45}
   \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 30}{\arabic{ct}\newline }
   \end{document}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

## solution to the second question.

The first argument is the number of *untouched* lines, the second argument is the object to be inserted and the optional argument is a corrective term: the number of `supplementary lines`  which should be narrower (w.r.t. the number of lines calculated by TeX) – just as in the `wrapfigure` environment.

I propose this simple code, which works fine for one-lined captions. For longer captions, you'll have to make a correction, in terms of the number of supplementary lines, with the command:
`\myInsertBoxL[no of supplementary lines]{width}{graphic file}{caption text}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\input{insbox.tex}

\newcommand\myInsertBoxL[4][]{\InsertBoxL{0}{%
\parbox[t]{#2}{%
\includegraphics[width=#2]{#3}
\captionof{figure}{#4}
}}%
[\numexpr#1 + 3\relax]}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\myInsertBoxL{0.45\textwidth}{example-image-a}{}
\noindent\lipsum[1-2]

\myInsertBoxL[2]{0.45\textwidth}{example-image-b}
{A useful caption. A useful caption. A useful caption.}%
\noindent\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernand Hm. In my MWE I have zero in optional argument. Take a look at screenshot. 7 lines are narrower... not zero...btw, it is your construction of adding pictures (heh).

Comment: @Bernand I understood the meaning of parametres. But, why does this construction spoil it?!

Comment: and in wrapfigure it is number of ALL narrow lines. but there it is just correction - the number that will add to the number of lines calculated by TeX.

Isn't it?!

Comment: Yes. In my opinion, it is simpler than `wrapfigure`.

Comment: @Bernand but you can see that with `threeparttable` spoils it. I need to add this correction not only for adding place for caption (for example), but in order to make normal wrapping... It is wrong.

Comment: and what your throught about the first question, which is more important and more complex? 
And I am sorry for wrong spelling of "Bernand". I print it automatically...

Comment: I've added a solution, which doesn't require `threeparttable`  (but you must specify the width of the image), and is simple to use. Please have a look at my completed answer

Comment: Oh,there is no mystical effect. It's great. Sure, I should check its work with enviroments and lists, where I have a lot of problems with wrapping text.

And by the way, do you have an idea about the first question?

Comment: `insbox` can work in the neighbourhood of lists, but it's a liitle harder to make it work. I have a solution, though, if you need it. For your first question, at first sight, I do not really understand what it does, but I' take a closer look tomorrow. That said, my solution works for one-lined captions. Do you have that many longer captions?

Comment: No, everywhere in my doc I have one-lined captions. 

I need your solution for lists. please, give it to me. all of my time I am just trying to solve problem of wrapping in theorems, in lists. Particulary, when my picture is located to the left of the list

Comment: Please look at my solutions to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268319/align-table-and-wrap-text-arround-it/268423#268423) and [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192348/wrapping-text-around-a-table-in-enumeration-environment-with-cutout-and-parshape/192443#192443). If necessary, post an example with what you've tried.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297627/how-to-wrap-pictures-in-lists-in-theorems-with-formulas


There are my problems... Please, take look at my own answer -- there are my tryings. I will try your variants also.